# React - componentDidUpdate called infinite times

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and I feel I didn't catch the component lifecycle flow, this is the component I have:

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchMyWishlist, fetchSpecificBook } from '../actions/index';

class Cart extends Component {

  static contextTypes = {
        router:PropTypes.object
    };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { currentCart:[], currentBook:[], wishlist:[] };

    var self = this;
    if (this.props.authenticated){
      this.props.fetchMyWishlist(this.props.signedInUserInfo._id).then(function(data){
        self.setState({ currentCart: data});
      });
    }
    else {
      this.context.router.push('/signin');
    }
  }

  componentWillMount(){}

  componentDidMount(){
    // I get undefined here
    console.log("component has been mounted: "+this.state.currentCart.payload);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
    var jsonObj = this.state.currentCart.payload;
    console.log("test: "+JSON.stringify(this.state.currentCart.payload));
    var self = this;
    if ((jsonObj) && (jsonObj.data)){   
      return jsonObj.data.map(function(book){
          self.props.fetchSpecificBook(book.itemID);
      });
    }
  }


  render() {
    console.log("rendering");

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <h3>Your wishlist</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
  return {
    currentCart: state.bookReducer.currentCart,
    currentBook: state.bookReducer.currentBook,
    authenticated: state.auth.authenticated,
    signedInUserInfo:state.auth.signedInUserInfo
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchMyWishlist, fetchSpecificBook})(Cart);
```

This is what I'm doing: inside the constructor the action `fetchMyWishlist` is called and it returns an array of book ids. The reducer updates the `currentCart` state with the result of `fetchMyWishlist` action.

First thing I don't understand is why in componentDidMount `this.state.currentCart.payload` is undefined.
So I try to do my operations inside `componentDidUpdate` where `this.state.currentCart.payload` is defined and I can iterate through it.
Here for each book I try to retrieve additional information via `fetchSpecificBook` action.
The problem here is that I get infinite number of action calls.
What I'd like to do is to store all additional books information into an array.

How do I go about this?

Comment: i will suggest to the lifecycle methods and there flow: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle , you will get  the reason of the error.

Comment: I have removed `redux` tags because you are using redux library but not the redux architecture.

Answer (score 0):

> Why in componentDidMount this.state.currentCart.payload is undefined?

When you are inside a constructor, you can simply set the state like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        ...
    };
}
```

Your selector should give you the data you need as props() when the component is mounted. Are you manipulating the store and therefore get new props which is resulting in an infinite re-render loop?

Comment: When self.props.fetchSpecificBook is called inside componentDidUpdate the reducer updates the state and so componentDidUpdate is called again, this produces an infinite loop. I guess I should organize the code in a different way but I dont know how.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor is not a good place to be fetching and setting state. I suspect that's the root of your issue. Try `componentWillMount` instead.

```
  state = {
    currentCart: [],
    currentBook: [],
    widhlist: []
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    const { authenticated, fetchMyWishlist, signedInUserInfo } = this.props;

    if (authenticated){
      fetchMyWishlist(signedInUserInfo._id).then(function(data){
        this.setState({ currentCart: data});
      });
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    console.log("component has been mounted: "+this.state.currentCart.payload);
  }
```